# Determine first table in a data set

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I am trying to determine if i have the first table out of a dataset, however the problem i having by using this

```
if(ds.Tables[0].TableName == "tablename")
```

is that the dataset is dynamically built depending on the results from the database, for example an AC unit will have Fan Speed table however a boiler unit will not that will have a Temp table.

Currently i have

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet("AllUsageEquipment");
foreach (var chanID in allChanIDs)
{
   DataTable dt = api.GetTotalEquipmentForAreaLevel(startDate, endDate, period, utility, AreaLevel, AreaLevelID, unitType, chanID);
   dt.TableName = dt.Rows[0]["Quantity"].ToString();
   ds.Tables.Add(dt);
}

DataTable dtExport = new DataTable();
dtExport.Columns.Add("DateStamp", typeof(string));

foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
{
  dtExport.Columns.Add(dt.Rows[0]["Quantity"].ToString(), typeof(int));

  foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
  {
    if(//code to determine first datatable)
  }

}
```

As you can see the data set is made up dynamically, using the Quantity returned from the database ('Fan Speed' example)

So i am struggling to get the first table in the dataset.

Comment: is your first code snippet really using an `=` and not `==`?

Comment: Shouldn't you write `ds.Tables[0].TableName == "tablename"`?

Comment: Can you give your core table with the Quantity property in it a name and then use ds.Tables["MyQuantityTable"] instead?

Comment: If `Quantity` is an `int`-column, you really want to  make it the `TableName` of the `DataTable`? It's not really clear what you are trying to achieve or what you're struggling with.

Comment: Why can't you use `unitType` to differentiate the tables?

Comment: Why not set a variable : DataTable quantityTbl = ds.Tables.Add(dt);